# How to update UI in Asp .Net after running a Task or during task running?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, webforms, task

I am using asp .net webforms and I have a button that generates an Excel report, it's a long operation.
I want a Label's text to be updated during task running and after it complete.

Button Click:

```
 protected void btnExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     FetchAllFilesAsync(false);
 }
```

Called Function :

```
 private async Task FetchAllFilesAsync(bool isPDF = false)
 {
     await Task.Run(() => { DownLoadAllAsyncExcelAndPDFS(isPDF); });
 }
```

Task Function

```
private void DownLoadAllAsyncExcelAndPDFS(bool isPDF = false)
{
   //Do Some Work
}
```

Comment: Observation: Task.Run is a waste of thread pool resources. Your request thread will just be sitting around doing nothing, may as well use it to call the method synchronously.

Comment: You're probably going to want to combine a [background processing technology](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-run-background-tasks-in-aspnet) with a method of pushing notifications to a client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`async` on ASP.NET yields to the thread pool, not the HTTP client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net). You'll need to use AJAX, SignalR, or a similar technology to have the server send updates to the client.

Comment: Yes, it looks like no way to do that without a third party. I did it with [Pushy](https://pushy.me/) to send a notification when the task completed to javascript